# Chunking a large video file and appending to BLOB for Continuous playback

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, blob, playback

**I tried MediaSource API but it's not working correctly** due to the latest browser does not support some of the functions from MediaSource API for example webkitMediaSourceURL.

https://wwwhtml5rockscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tutorials/streaming/multimedia/en/

I'm looking for open source one javascript.

I tried another example but There is a problem with seamless playback, a gap between two chunks is noticeable.

```
var player = document.querySelector('video');

getBlob('webm-chunk1')
.then(function (chunk1) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(chunk1); 
  player.src = url;
  player.play();

  return getBlob('webm-chunk2');
})
.then(function (chunk2) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(chunk2); 

  player.addEventListener('ended', handler, false);

  function handler() {
    player.removeEventListener('ended', handler);

    player.src = url;
    player.load();
    player.play();
  }
});
```

Comment: have you found out ? i have ran into the same issue and im wondering how it's done

Comment: Nope, still not